# How can in angular2 parse a template segment with model data?

Tags: angular

Let's say now I have template segment as below,

```
This is just a simple string - my name is {{name}}, I'm {{nationality}}, ...
```

and I have a model object, how can I parse it in angularjs 2?

I'm still quite new to ng2, now I am seeking something similar to  [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) or [razor template engine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine), just to parse a string like above.

Comment: Angular templates normally are statically compiled but also dynamic compilation support is available. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960 for an example.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more context. Parse into what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @codeepic the above answer should be what I just want :) you may click into the url